# I need to concat year and date for the SQLite in the .once statement

Tags: sqlite, csv, dynamic, strftime

I need to use .once ./sample_yyyy_mm.csv and here, i like to make the yyyy and mm to be dynamic and hence used

.once select "./sample1_" || select strftime('%m','now') || "_" || select strftime('%Y','now') - 1 ||".csv";

But this is not working. can you pls help.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL for SQLite could be (see below re the `-1`):-

```
SELECT strftime('./sample1_%m_%Y.csv','now');
```

e.g. the result would be **./sample1_02_2023.csv**

- Everything, including the concatenation of the prefix and suffix is all undertaken in the single invocation of the strftime function.

It is unclear what your expectation of using **`-1`** is. It's use if included   as it was is to try to perform a mathematical operation on a string/text value, that string value will then be considered 0 and the final result will be **-1.0**

If appears that you are trying to get the previous year in which case the query above could be modified to be:-

```
SELECT strftime('./sample1_%m_%Y.csv','now','-1 year');
```

e.g. the result would then be **./sample1_02_2022.csv** (obviously based upon the date when the query is run).

- note that `year` could also be `years` and you can use other modifiers such as `day` or `days`, `month` or `months`.

  - see **[SQLite Date and Time Functions - 3. Modifiers](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#modifiers)**

With regard to

```
`select "./sample1_" || select strftime('%m','now') || "_" || select strftime('%Y','now') - 1 ||".csv";`
```

This has a number of issues:-

- string/text literals (`./sample1_`,`_` and `.csv` ) need to be enclosed in single quotes not double quotes, otherwise they are considered to be component names (e.g. table/column names) depending upon where they appear and what the SQLite parser expects.
- subqueries, i.e. a SELECT within a SELECT need to be enclosed in parenthesises.

Applying the above you could have:-

```
`select './sample1_' || (select strftime('%m','now')) || '_' || (select strftime('%Y','now')) - 1 ||'.csv';`
```

**BUT** the result would be **-1.0** (due to the mathematical operation handling).

Without the `-1` (see above re modifiers) i.e. `select './sample1_' || (select strftime('%m','now')) || '_' || (select strftime('%Y','now')) ||'.csv';` the result would be **./sample1_02_2023.csv**

Comment: Thanks, this solves the concat part for me. The actual is this query would get me a dynamic filename. i need to run a  ".once ./sample1_02_2023.csv" how to get this output as an input for .once

Comment: The ask is, I need to pass dynamic filename to .once command

Comment: @MSBalaji you have not indicated which of the many possible thousands of programming languages  `.once` comes from. I have no idea whatsoever.